# win7 on macbook pro: is it safe to delete osx partition?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I've installed win7 on mbp using bootcamp by creating additional partition - so now I have 2 partitions (win and osx)
My question is: will win7 boot normally if I delete osx partition from windows (using tools like Acronis Disk Director) ?

picture of my partitions from win:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answering to myself: yes it is safe
source: own experience